# data.table: retrieve logical vector of matched keys between two data tables

Tags: r, data.table

Given this example with two data.table with only one column key each, I want a logical vector of keys in y thah are not found in x, but I can't guess the best way to do this in data.table (using data.table semantics):

```
#given
x = data.table(n=1:10,  key="n")
y = data.table(n=4:13,  key="n")

#i need:
y$n %in% x$n  # TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

These are my ugly options (in addition to the above)

```
x[, .(n, dummy = n)][y, !is.na(dummy)]
y[, .(n, dummy = F)][x, dummy:=T][]
```

Note that:

```
x[y, 1]
```

almost solves my question, it retrieves the `y` keys unmatched in `x` as `NA`, even when `x[y, "n"]` retrieve all keys in `y` not only the unmatched ones. But i did'nt find any documentation that support this.

Thanks in advance

EDIT:

Also i noted that data.table approaches are faster than %in% so i want to take advantage of this.

```
x = data.table(n = sample(1:1e8, size = 1e7), key = "n")
y = data.table(n = sample(1:1e8, size = 1e7), key = "n")

system.time(y$n %in% x$n)  # about a second
system.time(x[y, 1])       # about half a second
```

Comment: What's wrong with `y[, n %in% x$n]` or your original non-`data.table` `y$n %in% x$n`?

Comment: it's slower as far as i can test with system.time because %in% is base R, that is not as optimised as data.table

Comment: That's a relevant edit. It should be noted that `y$n %in% x$n` dwarfs all other expressions until `size=1e5` or `1e6`, at which point your join starts to break out ahead. But even with the example of `size=1e7`, the basic `%in%` is at worst 50% slower. While you might be able to squeeze a little extra juice out of that stone, is it worth the complexity to compromise readability for some milliseconds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `?"[.data.table"`:

> Advanced: Columns of x can now be referred to using the
> prefix x. and is particularly useful during joining to refer to x's
> join columns as they are otherwise masked by i's. For example, X[Y,
> .(x.a-i.a, b), on="a"].

so,

```
!is.na(x[y, x.n])
```

is the answer

Comment: elegant. If you don't want just the vector, but the values themselves: `data.table:::na.omit.data.table(x[x[y, x.n]])`

Answer (score 0):

If you want the indices, similar to what @r2evans said, just use `%in%` and `which`. Maybe something like this:
`which(x$n %in% y$n)`

Comment: I was sticking to the original *"I want a logical vector"*, not the same as indices on the vector.